# What plugin/technology is used in this XML sample to create graphics user interface in Java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, user-interface

In the past I used XAML or XML to declare interface in Windows Phone, WPF or Android application.

My student has provided me short xml sample and said that he would like to learn how to declare GUI in Java in this exact manner he showed me. I do NOT know what kind of solution/plugin/IDE/technology is used in this sample.

Maybe you know what exacly is that.

**I know that there are many XML solutions for Java but I am asking
   exacly about that below.**

```
<lay:StrategyLayout>
   <lay:StrategyPanel collapsible="false" orientation="VERTICAL" title="Main parameters">
      <lay:Control ID="A_CONTROL" label="Label A" parameterRef="A" xsi:type="lay:SingleSpinner_t" initValue="0"/>
      <lay:Control ID="B_CONTROL" label="Label B:" parameterRef="B" xsi:type="lay:SingleSpinner_t" initValue="0"/>
      <lay:Control ID="SIDE_CONTROL" xsi:type="lay:DropDownList_t" label="Side:" parameterRef="SIDE" initValue="0">
         <lay:ListItem enumID="e1" uiRep="BUY"/>
         <lay:ListItem enumID="e2" uiRep="SELL"/>
</lay:Control>
....
```

What plugin should I install in Eclipse to use that?

Comment: Looks like [FIXadtl](http://code.google.com/p/atdl4j/)